# In-line ∑ with super- and sub-scripts

Tags: positioning

How can I get ﻿an uppercase sigma (∑) with both a subscript and a superscript to appear in a sentence WITH the subscript BELOW the sigma and the superscript ABOVE the ∑ (and neither of the lower/raised FOLLOWING the sigma?

In a regular formula that is preceded and followed by a double space, everything works/looks fine.

Comment: `\sum\limits_0^n`  but publications almost never do that as it destroys the baseline spacing of the surrounding paragraph.

Comment: In inline equation  limits of summation aren't below and above sum symbol. You can force it with `limits`, for example  `$\sum\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$`.

Comment: Also $\displaystyle ...$